# How many possible arrangements of dominoes on a line?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let`s imagine a line of N fields (a 1-dimensional grid).

□□□□□□□□□□□□...

Now we take n dominoes (each domino is m fields long, e.g m=3 □□□ ).

*(I`m aware that 'domino' is for m != 2 wrong, but that makes the description easier)*

**How many possible arrangements of dominoes are possible?**

---> The dominoes may not overlap with each other.

---> The dominoes may not overlap with the beginning/first field.

---> BUT dominoes MAY overlap with the end/last field.

**EXAMPLE:**

N = 5 (□□□□□)

n = 2 (■■ und ◘◘)

m = 2

These 12 arrangements are possible:

■■◘◘□

■■□◘◘

■■□□◘◘

□■■◘◘

□■■□◘◘

◘◘■■□

□□■■◘◘

◘◘□■■

□◘◘■■

◘◘□□■■

□◘◘□■■

□□◘◘■■

Comment: If you have tiles of length $3$, is one allowed to have a $2$-cell overlap *or* a $1$-cell overlap with the righthand end of the board, or is only one of these allowed?

Comment: both, so in general m-1 fields may overlap with the right-hand end.

Comment: Then you can simply make the board $N+m-1$ cells long and require each tile to lie completely on the board.

Comment: yes, I wasn`t completely sure about that. But I have not found a solution with this modification either.

Comment: I could use the Domino -Tiling-Equation (by Kasteleyn 1961), but this does apply for $m = 2$ only!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrange the dominoes in some order, which can be done in $n!$ ways.

Now take the $N$ fields plus the $m\!-\!1$ "phantom fields" at the end, remove those $nm$ covered by the dominoes, and allocate those amongst the dominoes for ${N+m-1-nm+n \choose n}$ choices.

Overall:$$n!{N+n+m-1-nm \choose n} = n!{N- (n\!-\!1)(m\!-\!1) \choose n} $$

For your example, this gives $2!{5-1 \choose 2} = 12$ as expected